# External DHCP not working in Cisco Switch C3750

Tags: switching

I have Cisco Switch C3750 (IOS version 12.2 ) and I have four physical computers and one physical Dell t30 Server connected to it.  In Server, I have created DHCP with a Pool of IP Addresses.

How can I connect to the Server and receive IP addresses via DHCP to the computers through the Cisco switch?

I used Hyperterminal application and all I see is VLAN that created with IP Address.

Comment: I don't understand your question - you want the server to hand out DHCP to the 4 computers?

If so, stick them all in the same vlan (they'll be in the same vlan by default if you've not changed anything). If it's not working, it's likely your DHCP server isn't setup right.

Comment: Yes, you are right?  I am sorry to confuse you with my questions.  If my DHCP server setup right and you don't have to configure an IP address on the switch?  I mean it is managed the switch.

Comment: You don't need to configure an IP on the switch to use it, it's just useful :). Share the config you've got on the switch right now, I'll see if I can see anything obviously wrong.